# Hot fix between two remote git repositories

Tags: git, version-control, git-commit, git-push, git-remote

I have two git remote repositories, one is for test and the other is for production.

```
    git remote -v
    production      https://ejemplo@bitbucket.org/deploy/pr1.git (fetch)
    production      https://ejemplo@bitbucket.org/deploy/pr1.git (push)
    test    https://ejemplo@bitbucket.org/deploy/pr1_test.git (fetch)
    test    https://ejemplo@bitbucket.org/deploy/pr1_test.git (push)
```

When someone make a change, they work locally and push to the testing remote:

```
    git push test master
```

Someone makes the pull, test the change and if tis OK, push it to production.

```
    git push production master
```

The problem is when i have various changes to test before push to production, but i need to apply an inmediate hotfix. 
I cant push the hotfix to production without push al the others changes that are before it (not tested yet).

example:

```
    test repository : 
    test commit 6 - hotfix (i fix something) 
    test commit 5
    test commit 4
    test commit 3 - to this point is equal to production.
    test commit 2
    test commit 1
```

```
    Production repository: 
    production commit 3
    production commit 2
    production commit 1
```

I want to push the hotfix commit (commit 6) without push to production commit 4 and 5. Is possible to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: No. If you don't want the changes introduced by 4 and 5, you need make 6 on the base of 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trouble is that you're using repos to do what branches are meant for.  Out of curiosity, how do you deal with situations where a commit is rejected (but the commits after it are fine)?

Any solution (other than moving to a branch strategy suitable to your needs, after which you will likely find that a single repo would be not only sufficient but easier to deal with) is going to be messy.

All of the possible options boil down to rebasing commit 6 onto commit 3.  You don't *really* want that rebase going back into your test repo, as it will create a mess for all the developers.  But if that rebase *doesn't* go back to test, then eventually it has to be removed from production as well in order to get the repos back in sync.

```
Test Repo
1 --- 2 --- 3 --- 4 --- 5 --- 6 <--(master)

Prod Repo
1 --- 2 --- 3 <--(master)

Local
1 --- 2 --- 3 --- 4 --- 5 --- 6 <--(master)
```

Do a rebase; replace the commit numbers in this command with the corresponding SHA ID

```
git checkout master
git checkout -b temp_master
git rebase --onto 3 5
```

Now you have

```
Test Repo
1 --- 2 --- 3 --- 4 --- 5 --- 6 <--(master)

Prod Repo
1 --- 2 --- 3 <--(master)

Local
1 --- 2 --- 3 --- 4 --- 5 --- 6 <--(master)
             \
              6' <--(temp_master)
```

Now *you must test `6'`*.  This is a new state of the code that never existed before, and it is untested.  If `6` inadvertently depends on something in `4` or `5`, then `6'` is broken.

So you test, it works.  To get the hotfix into production

```
git push production temp_master:master
```

yielding

```
Test Repo
1 --- 2 --- 3 --- 4 --- 5 --- 6 <--(master)

Prod Repo
1 --- 2 --- 3 --- 6' <--(master)

Local
1 --- 2 --- 3 --- 4 --- 5 --- 6 <--(master)
             \
              6' <--(temp_master)
```

Now my advice is to finish acceptance testing of `4` and `5` ASAP, and then force push `master` to `production` and delete `temp_master`.

If you find you have to push `4` before `5` is ready to go, the it too will have to be rebased onto `6'`.

```
git rebase temp_master 4
git branch -f temp_master
```

(where again `4` is replaced with the commit's SHA).

Again, stop and retest, because something in `6'` might interact badly with `4` so `4'` is a new and untested state of the code.  All is well?  Then:

```
git push production temp_master:master
```

and you get

```
Test Repo
1 --- 2 --- 3 --- 4 --- 5 --- 6 <--(master)

Prod Repo
1 --- 2 --- 3 --- 6' -- 4' <--(master)

Local
1 --- 2 --- 3 --- 4 --- 5 --- 6 <--(master)
             \
              6' --- 4' <--(temp_master)
```

At this point, you might think that when you've tested `5` you might as well rebase it and just keep on trucking with the re-ordered branch in production.  Don't, unless you're willing to reorder the branch in test (and in everyone's local repo) as well, which will be a hassle.  At the end of the day, you need a common history, because even if you rebase `5` to get

```
Local
1 --- 2 --- 3 --- 4 --- 5 --- 6 <--(master)
             \
              6' --- 4' --- 5' <--(temp_master)
```

you may find that `6` and `5'` look the same - they have the same cumulative set of changes and the same result tree - but they are different commits and work based on one would have to be rebased to the other.

Answer (score -1):

In the test repo, run:

```
git format-patch hotfix~..hotfix
```

which will generate a patch file. In the production repo, run:

```
git am the.patch
```

Comment: I would advise against it.  First, that applies the patch to production without having tested the resulting state of the code.  Second, the production history is now divergent from all other repos, so you'll have to do clean-up at least as messy as the later steps of the procedure I outlined.

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger Agreed. The purpose of my answer is for OP to achieve exactly what he wants, not to improve on his process which is a bigger topic, and quite frankly, beside the point.

Comment: There are multiple ways to give OP "exactly what he wants".  At least one such way - as outlined in my answer - doesn't have the problems I pointed out in your answer.  Regardless, telling someone when they're about to step on a land mine is *never* "beside the point"

Comment: Your answer does not give OP exactly what he wants, not without having him significantly alter his process anyway. I'm not arguing that such alteration is good or bad, but just pointing out that fact.

Comment: And I think you are assuming too much in terms of OP's circumstances. Just because they want to cherry pick a hotfix into their production branch, does not necessarily mean that they are stepping on a land mine. You are assuming that OP's system consists of code, and hence a change somewhere can affect other places in an obscure way. OP could simply be maintaining a static web site consisting of static web pages, where a change is just a change without much ramification.

Comment: Wrong on all counts. My response *does* give him exactly what he wants. The fact that it is a process with steps that have to be followed does not mean it "modifies his process". You're the one making assumptions by supposing that he *has* a process, when in fact he's asking what process would achieve this result. Second, you clearly don't understand what landmine one would be stepping on by using your process, because it has nothing to do with whether the system consists of code or whether your process would harm production.  That said...

Comment: ...giving the more generally "safe" solution is *not* assuming too much.  Giving the dangerous answer assumes too much, because it assumes his circumstances are such that he won't get burned by applying the procedure you're recommending.  Regardless, I'm not debating this further; our answers' scores speak for themselves.

Comment: LOL, not sure if you realize that, when you so confidently assert that I assume that he has a process, you are, in fact, assuming that he does not have one. Based on the fact that OP has a testing environment, and him asking about this "hotfix" scenario, I think it's more logical to assume that he does have a process and ordinarily does follow it, and this is only an exceptional case.

Comment: Furthermore, if he doesn't have a process, you are suggesting that he adopts one. I'm not sure how I would be wrong in saying "your answer does not give him exactly what he wants without significantly altering his process" then?

Comment: I fully understand the kind of danger one might get into by deploying a change without going testing, which is why I agreed to your original comment to begin with.

Comment: It is also realistically possible that somebody looked at the actual fix, and decided either that it is unlikely that it will fail in production, or that the cost of not having it in production asap far outweighs the risk of pushing it into production without thorough testing.